# Possible bug in libc++ for mac os ,string destructor is not called when string obj goes out of scope

Tags: ios, c++11, destructor, stdstring, libc++

In `libc++` i have found that basic_string `destructor` does not gets called , once string goes out of the scope the memory is freed by calling delete operator rather than calling its `destructor` and then calling the delete operator from `destructor`, why so?

Can some one explain this?
see the sample program

```
void * operator new ( size_t len ) throw ( std::bad_alloc )
{
    void * mem = malloc( len );
    if ( (mem == 0) && (len != 0) ) 
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    return mem;
}

void operator delete ( void * ptr ) throw()
{
    if ( ptr != 0 ) 
        free( ptr );
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    std::string  mystr("testing very very very big string for string class");
    std::string mystr2(mystr1.begin(),mystr.end());
}
```

Put break point on new and delete and then check the call stack.
new operator gets called from basic_string class while the delete gets called from the end of main, while ideally basic_string `destructor` should have called first and then the delete operator should be called via `deallocate` call of `allocator`, this is valid for 2nd string creation.

Comment: Have you enabled optimization? Why do you consider it *ideal* that the destructor is called? Since the only observable effect of the destructor is the call to delete, this is allowed by the as-if rule.

Comment: I have not enabled any optimization, i know for basic_string it will call operator new from assembly code but in 2nd string creation case it uses allocator and call the new operator via allocate method.
I can also see destructor in basic_string class and by looking the code i feel that its written to be called at the time of destruction for the case when string was created through allocator.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same thing in the debugger that you are; I don't know for sure, but I suspect that stuff is getting inlined.  The destructor for `basic_string` is very small; a single test (for the small string optimization), and then a call to the allocator's `deallocate` function (through `allocate_traits`). `std::allocator`s allocate function is also quite small, just a wrapper around `operator delete`.

You could test this by writing your own allocator.  (Later: see below)

More stuff that I generated while investigating this question; read on if you're interested.

*[Note: there's a bug in your code - in the second line you wrote: `mystr1.begin(),mystr.end())` - where is `mystr1` declared?]*

Assuming that's a typo, I tried some slightly different code:

```
#include <string>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

int news = 0;
int dels = 0;

void * operator new ( size_t len ) throw ( std::bad_alloc )
{
    void * mem = malloc( len );
    if ( (mem == 0) && (len != 0) ) 
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    ++news;
    return mem;
}

void operator delete ( void * ptr ) throw()
{
    ++dels;
    if ( ptr != 0 ) 
        free( ptr );
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    {
    std::string mystr("testing very very very big string for string class");
    std::string mystr2(mystr.begin(),mystr.end());
    std::cout << "News = " << news << "; Dels = " << dels << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "News = " << news << "; Dels = " << dels << std::endl;

}
```

If you run this code, it prints (at least for me):

```
News = 2; Dels = 0
News = 2; Dels = 2
```

which is exactly what it should.

If I toss the code into [compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZTUAHAvVAOwGdK0AbVAV2J4OmAIIcAtiADkABmmk0Exnh6YA8mwDCCAIZtgmGfICUpDgOLIj0gKSyAnLYBMAZjxtkPflgDUt1y0OAiEDAOx7UXsnNw8vH0x/QLZMAHdwyOiXd09vPwCtVmDiTF0JDNkoyuiPAl8U1I4kgBFfWQCAIUzHWt8sHiaA1vbXLurxhwA3VDx0XwAqXyZMYl0iYnq03whfDjwAL0wAfTq1Nl8TXwIEYlRU7d2CdBAQACNddCPdHj5kC%2B6nAB2MZVJyOaazBa%2BCSYCQtaHfX47M7/UYAmoAMweEBhcKGQzalxcADYSdsUWAwATZJciRMso5rrd7sFnm8Pl8fqhkBATJ10Y4XF1nB0Ghx%2BfTHCUCIJzriJaDbIDmt1QRC5stVus%2Bpg1AREjt1VDmBtLky7rz0cCBTFhR1%2BuK0ZKHHgsTsTb5KdSLv5ndEMSVMO6QqiQVllaqamw6hJdB4IL1dMRgMhSL40Jw6sg9BtFkngJNbABWLpF5p0xXWv1VxWOVkvYoeYDQgCexQgLmc%2BuCTd8kxWLb7A6HxEHrzwzcbBl8GJIj1Cza8ug44uczj5TtrDnrICnzYkbZCzhxh%2BIADpXphgPGzAfimfMGx0LyNyCAPRvhnbp4vND8OoFAU/hrgAcmkgyuK0nZJFoQFijBQGdp0vjNLqEFQWuCGBDqAxYVojxso%2B6A8AqX5KiqlQfl%2BO5/gBgSIaB4HwtBgHYfBrH4UhowoWhzGYRxOEQbB2E7kRJFOmClYUaI0hmDwMhFgobAyLQCioDIsEikKuyWNYwGuKppAEMYslmAA1iARayKQ8nSAALEpJkMDIChcNZxlyLJpBwLASBKCoahkBQED%2BaoKwoDw%2BjAK4DjWRiqj6sQXAQK8TlKDC0aaDwLZOfgJTICw/ZcJ55DRrqJlmEwLDsMVAC0rJDMgQpCrQdm%2BPVTw8HgrxDF1rxNVpIrtQA6oiI2YAAHiEuhebZimkMpJXqXYbi0L4qSEAgvgTQAHMStXEm1S7Tq4Z4OGe8hGRV5mWdZtkOQtTnLa5IDuddNkyM4jlLS5V2eSYZj9klrDKXZQA%3D%3D), then I see both the calls to `basic_string::~basic_string()`, exactly as I expect. (Well, I see *three* of them, but one of them is in an exception handling block, which ends with a call to `_Unwind_resume`).

Later - this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

int news = 0;
int dels = 0;

template <class T>
class MyAllocator
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    MyAllocator() noexcept {}

    template <class U>
    MyAllocator(MyAllocator<U>) noexcept {}

    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        ++news;
        return static_cast<T*>(::operator new(n*sizeof(T)));
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t)
    {
        ++dels;
        return ::operator delete(static_cast<void*>(p));
    }

    friend bool operator==(MyAllocator, MyAllocator) {return true;}
    friend bool operator!=(MyAllocator, MyAllocator) {return false;}
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    {
    typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char>> S;
    S mystr("testing very very very big string for string class");
    S mystr2(mystr.begin(),mystr.end());
    std::cout << "Allocator News = " << news << "; Allocator Dels = " << dels << std::endl;
    }
std::cout << "Allocator News = " << news << "; Allocator Dels = " << dels << std::endl;
}
```

prints:

```
 Allocator News = 2; Allocator Dels = 0
 Allocator News = 2; Allocator Dels = 2
```

which confirms that the allocator is getting called.

Comment: But once you add  below lines in the code and put break point on operator delete definition, you would see the call trace as expected.

str2.get_allocator().deallocate(const_cast<char *>(str2.data()) 
str2.length());

Behavior of destructor call and explicit deallocate call is different, i found this while debugging something where my app is using DLL and when DLL calls stringstream.str() method in such case new operator of DLL gets called while delete operator at Application level gets called when we explicitly calls deallocate by adding the above line then delete operator of DLL called.

Comment: In case of libstdc++ new and delete operator at application level was getting called.